# How to update the description of Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there such a placeholder envisaged for that, or is the topic name the only attribute that must be sufficiently descriptive?

Comment: if with description you mean parameters, you can update them via:
 > bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper host:port --alter --topic my-topic 
    --config x=y, where x=parameter and y the value you want to apply to it

Comment: @asier : I think, OP is asking for some description level attribute

Comment: yep, totally mislead that!

Comment: But config parameters cannot be custom. So, that doesn't help.

Comment: Topic configurations are just a map. I think they can be whatever you want

Answer (score 2):

No, There is no placeholder where you can describe what a kafka topic contains as a topic property. You should make the topic name self explanatory.

You can see what all properties a topic can have : 
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs